# Вывести сатью по названию в Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Есть сайт на Opencart. Там в описании есть таблицы. Они прописаны не в самом описании, а созданы через Статьи и подгружаются туда через - [таблица 1] , [таблица 2] и т.п.

Пример на новом - http://new1.sparkavto.ru/katalog-tovarov/shtatnye-kamery-zadnego-vida/dodge_camera/spark-d1
Пример на старом - https://sparkavto.ru/dodge_camera/spark-d1

А сами таблицы находятся тут - https://prnt.sc/tdboxm
Нужно чтобы они подгружались туда автоматически, когда вставляется тег, например - [таблица1].

А сама эта таблица находится в Каталог - Статьи - Таблица1
Подскажите где это может находиться на старом сайте, нужно просто скопировать от туда готовое решение

Comment: уточняйте версию магазина тегом при постановке вопроса по opencart. И удалите ваши предыдущие воросы на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

`Opencart` из коробки не поддерживает шорткоды. Значит обработку оных дописывали разработчики предыдущего сайта либо использовано стороннее расширние.

Если это самопис - искать надо в `catalog/controller/product/product.php`. Искать `$data['description']` и смотреть, как там реализована подмена шорткода.